# Convert String to Marker in Google Map to remove the old Marker in the Map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a checkboxlist where the user can select some routes then a reponse is being getting from the server. I have method gotoLocation to upadte the location of the markers as well to add a new marker in the map when a new one is being inserted into the table on the serverside with the same route.

I had problem with adding a new marker to the map before so when I inserted data for a new marker with the same selected route in my database table, the new inserted one was not added to the map.  I stored the id and  Marker in the HashMap before  I solved this problem by storing the data of the marker as `String` in the HashMap in this case the new inserted data is being added to the map as marker.

Now in the `Update block` I need to convert this data `latit,longit, rout_dirc`  to marker  to remove the old one from the map and HashMap before updating its location. How can I do that in my case? How can I remove the old marker from the map since I dont have Marker in the HashMap now also I cant use `marker.remove()` to delete the old one?

I appreciate any help

**Code:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    static HashMap<Integer, String> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    static String marker_string;

    static Marker marker = null;
    private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
            String route_direct) {
        final float zoom = 11;
        LatLng ll = null;
        if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
            // Update the location.
            marker_string = markerMap.get(id);              
            String[] marker_string_split = marker_string.split(",");
            double latit = Double.parseDouble(marker_string_split[0]);
            double longit = Double.parseDouble(marker_string_split[1]);
            String rout_dirc = marker_string_split[2];

            LatLng LL_2 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt2 = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(LL_2);

            // This here doest work.
            marker.remove();

            // Remove from the HashMap tp add the new one.
            markerMap.remove(id);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(ll);
            marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);

            String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
            String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);
            String data = lat1 + "," + lng1 + "," + route_direct;
            markerMap.put(id, data);
            zoom();

        } else {
            // Add a new  marker 
            String lat1 = Double.toString(lat);
            String lng1 = Double.toString(lng);
            String data = lat1 + "," + lng1 + "," + route_direct;
            markerMap.put(id, data);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title(route_direct)
                    .position(ll);
            marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
            zoom();


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your marker in `marker.remove();` is set to null and it won't do any good unless you have a reference of the markers you want to delete. If you want to remove all old markers, then you can try the following:

```
mMap = super.getMap();
map.clear();
```

This removes everything. Otherwise, when you add markers you should have a reference if you need to delete it later.

For example, your marker variable is:

```
Marker marker = map.addMarker(..);
```

Then you can remove it by `marker.remove();`
Hope this makes sense;

Comment: I dont want to remove all  markers on the map I jsut want to remove the marker with specific `id` to update its location.

Comment: I have an idea, but I think it's a little dumb. But you can try it. So if you have the id of your marker, remove the lat/lng from the HashMap by getting it from the given id. Add any new lat/lng points that you need and then push your new set of lat/lng points onto the map by doing a loop of the map. Then, all of your markers are still there except for the one that's been removed.

Comment: I have not tried your comment solution proposal  but I got it to work  with `HashMap<Integer, Marker>` sine one of my problem was that the table id was incremented by one when the record was updated and I  proceed on the assumption that  it is the same id. Thanks for your support.

Comment: have u find proper working solution?  if yes than help me

Answer (score 0):

**mapView.clear()**

it will remove all markers in the map,
you can also refer the google official documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker